# How to install hp deskjet 3515

Tags: software-installation

How can i find free drivers in order to print my printer hp deskjet 3515 using linux and ubuntu in my pc?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should install HPLIP

`sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui`

for additional info take a look at [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing)